# get the value of a TextField component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component on react (with the help of materialui):

```
export default function AddToDo() {


    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div style={{
            display: "flex"
        }}>
            <TextField className={classes.textField} label="Add todo"></TextField>
            <Button variant="contained" >Submit</Button>
        </div>
    )

}
```

basically it's a text box and a button. When the button is pressed, I want to call a method (that is declared above the code I showed) called addNew(param1). I want param1 to be the value that the user introduces inside the text field. How can I achieve this? Basically something like this:

```
<Button onclick=addNew(value inside the textfield) variant="contained" >Submit</Button>
```

Comment: See controlled text components (`TextField` would be one of them), and pass that value into `addNew()`.

Comment: 2 methods. One is assign a `ref` to the input so that you can access the DOM element using normal javascript. Second is to use in a controlled state environment where you already know the value of your input `state`. In this case, you should call for the parent method props which keep the state the controlled input.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a state to store the value of the field and one callback to set the value:

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState("")

const fieldChangeHandler = React.useCallback((event) => setText(event.currentTarget.value))
```

And then add these properties to TextField component:

```
onChange={fieldChangeHandler}
value={text}
```

Then the value will be stored on `text` variable